# Spatial database design

Tags: postgis, database

I am designing a spatial database and I wanted to ask if it is a good idea to use inheritance to store objects that share certain attributes, but whose geometry differs since some are points, lines and others are polygons?

Comment: Inheritance is a potentially powerful tool, but I'd suggest to use declarative partitioning on geometry type instead; much easier to maintain and access, i.e. a query joining on the partitioned table can be completely unaware of the partitioning and still benefit from pruning + specific spatial indexation dynamically.